# Difference between $compile and the compile function on a directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to retrieve my template for a directive using a repository I have built that returns a promise that resolves to the contents of the template.

What is the difference between using the `compile` function in a directive and using the `$compile` service in the `link` function?

**Compile Function**

```
compile: function (element, attrs) {
    templateRepository.get('Shared/Login').then(function (result) {
        element.replaceWith(result);
    });
}
```

This renders the HTML, but the scope is not bound to the DOM elements.

**Using $compile**

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    templateRepository.get('Shared/Login').then(function (result) {
        elem.html(result);
        $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
    });
}
```

This works as expected.

What is the difference here?

Answer (score 3):

[**$compile**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile):

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template
>   function, which can then be used to link scope and the template
>   together.
>
> The compilation is a process of walking the DOM tree and matching DOM
>   elements to directives.

So `$compile` does the Angular processing on whatever DOM elements are handed to it.

During `$compile` the **Compile Function** within all found directives is run. Note that each directive's compile function is executed just once, no matter how many instances of that directive there are.

When the template function produced by `$compile` is executed ("to link scope and the template together") then each directive's link function is executed (with the scope passed in as the first parameter).

So `$compile` transforms the DOM.  While the directive's compile function is what's run, for that directive, during that transformation.

Here's a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj4ms/4/) you can experiment with which shows the order of execution.

Comment: So the directives `compile` function does no linking to scope, only creates a template from the directive and the element it is attached to? If true, then using the `$compile` service is the correct way to do what I want?

Comment: This `compiledResult = $compile(elem.contents())` does no linking against scope.  This `compiledResult(scope)` or `$compile(elem.contents())(scope)` does.  So the `$compile` itself doesn't link, but executing the function it returns (the template function) against a scope does.

Comment: But also note, neither `$compile` not executing the resulting template function adds the element to the dom.  You can have a compiled element that is not yet on the DOM, or vice-versa.

Comment: Very well explained!! Adding it to the DOM is done in the `elem.html(result)` correct?

Comment: Thanks!  Yep- in that case it's added before it's compiled, which is perfectly fine to do.

Comment: Could you accomplish the same thing using the directives compile function? Or do you have to do it in the linking function to pass the scope into the compile?

Comment: Two issues with doing it in the compile.  One, like you mention, there's no scope available in the compile function.  And compile is only called once for a directive- no matter how many instances there are of it.  So it's like a constructor function for the directive.  Thus, using the compile function you couldn't have multiple copies of the directive with different html.

Answer (score 1):

I think, **Compile Function** is a bit more agile:

From docs:

> A compile function can have a return value which can be either a
>   function or an object.
>
> returning a (post-link) function - is equivalent to registering the
>   linking function via the link property of the config object when the
>   compile function is empty.
>
> returning an object with function(s) registered via pre and post
>   properties - allows you to control when a linking function should be
>   called during the linking phase. See info about pre-linking and
>   post-linking functions below.