# Angular Directive's compile method called more than once

Tags: angularjs

So I've read in several places (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197073/difference-between-compile-and-the-compile-function-on-a-directive-in-angular?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/)) that a directive's compile method is only called once even if there are multiple instances of the directive and the link function is called for each instance but in this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/screenm0nkey/pUrG6/1/) the compile method gets called 3 times for the 3 instances. Why is that?

```
<focus-tooltip></focus-tooltip>
<focus-tooltip></focus-tooltip>
<focus-tooltip></focus-tooltip>

angular.module('app', [])
.directive('focusTooltip', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        compile : function () {
            console.log(this)
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compile function is called once for **each** element that uses the directive. The term *instances* did not mean that the compile function is only called once per ngApp. This means the compile function is called once even if there are clones of that element. For example ng-repeat creates clones of an element. See this [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5NDQ5e2Bga2h1XVMyB3?p=preview) that demonstrates this behavior.